# pylab not found - networkx python 2.7

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to run a simulator (developed by someone else) and make it work. I don't know Python but have started learning it. Could someone please look at the error below and advice me if it could be fixed or what it means. It should generate an image file at the end but it doesn't.

The error is:

[image]

Comment: if you simply run python and try `import pylab` what happens?  It looks to me like it's not installed, so I expect an error here even without networkx.

Comment: thanks for your reply but after running the command i get: >>> import pylab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pylab

Comment: Is there any way I could do a clean installation of Python (windows) with all these packages installed. I need this in Python 2

Comment: @user2119807 you can't just edit the question with a newer question, mark the answer that helped you as accepted and ask a new question about your new error independently. I rolled back your last edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't have the six Python module installed in your python version 2.6. You can find it on pypi.

To install it:

```
$ easy_install six
```

if 2.6 is not your default version, use instead:

```
$ easy_install-2.6 six
```

Comment: Still gets the same errors; install pip didn't help

Comment: you should install `six` not `pip`

Comment: after running easy_install six, I got: Searching for six
Best match: six 1.10.0
Processing six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg
six 1.10.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using c:\python27\lib\site-packages\six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for six
Finished processing dependencies for six---------------------------(which means (I think) I installed it.

Comment: actually you installed it in the version 2.7 while you need it in the version 2.6. so try: `easy_install-2.6 six`

Comment: thanks for your reply but I am running 2.7 then why to install it on 2.6. OR are you suggesting suggesting to use 2.6 instead

Comment: @user2119807 because your paylab and matplotlib are installed in pythobn 2.6... check the error

Comment: I have now installed everything on 2.5 as the software was developed in 2.5. I managed to install the corresponding version for networkX and matplotlib. The application seems to working a part from generating the output image. I now get the error (please click on the link above in the original post) .. many thanks